# F5 LTM: Running openssl s_client -connect from a partition?

Tags: openssl, command-line-interface, f5

At my job, we've got a https coupling with a 3rd party configured in a partition on a F5 LTM. That connection fails to initialize. Now, there's the nifty "openssl s_client -connect" command to check this, but can you run that from a non-common partition (and if yes, how)?

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you are in CLI, did you try `cd /yourpartition` and then run your command ?

Comment: OK, I'd totally forgotten about that, but that only works in tmsh, where openssl is not a known command... and in bash, the cd doesn't work for obvious reasons. But at least I can traceroute to the remote host on the specified port. That is at least a step forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I've found the solution, and perhaps [Eugène Adell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7748072/eug%C3%A8ne-adell) hinted at it at the time. What you do is go into tmsh, cd to the partition, then run the command by invoking bash from tmsh. So:

```
    (/mypartition) (tmos) bash -c '(echo -ne "GET <url> <headers>"; cat) |\
     openssl s_client -connect <ip>:<port>'
```